# Javascript not working, when used with angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using *MEAN stack* for development.

- I have 3 drop-downs, lets say **dropdown 1**, **dropdown 2**, **dropdown 3**.
- When I select an *`option`* from **dropdown 1**, **droppdown** 2 will be filled with options.
- When I select an option from **dropdown 2**, **dropdown 3** will be filled with options.

  To achieve this I am using javascript, which will fill the dropdowns dynamically based on the user's selection.

Now, everything is working smooth, when run my script on jsfiddle, but when I add same code in my front-end page, then all dropdowns are showing no options.


For code refer to : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/16212/)

Why this is happening?

Comment: Whole approach is completely wrong and backwards in an angular app. That data should be passed into a controller then passed to the view through angular scope and let angular render the view and manage events

Comment: In AngularJS, The `select` directive is used together with [`ngModel`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) to provide data-binding between the scope and the `<select>` control (including setting default values). It also handles dynamic `<option>` elements, which can be added using the [`ngRepeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) or [`ngOptions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) directives. For more information, see [AngularJS select Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select).